# view image magento 2.3.2 after import with magmi 7.23 of product with url

Tags: magento2.3.2

I installed magento 2.3.2 and magmi 7.23, everything works fine.
Import products: ok
result import images in pub / media / catalog: ok
but in the frontend of the store, the image does not display, I get a logo image of magento.
can you help me ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

to generate a new image cache.